# How to get X-Axis value of google area chart without using chart.getSelection method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, google-visualization

I need to find resolution of graph.for that I need first two values from X-axis values(which is time values) displayed on google chart but without any click events like chart.getSelection()graph example given here.
[image]

Also values keep changing when graph zoomed hence values are dynamic.Thankyou

Comment: ok thanks I'll check this and let u know

Comment: getHaxisvalue() method is giving some calculated random time,which is not present in my json data.I tried giving position as 0 and 1 for first and second values but it is giving different values.can u help please @WhiteHat